# Using the Like / Share Buttons on web page - formatting?

Tags: css, facebook-like

I placed the Like / Share buttons on a web page which has a black background.

Next to the share button is text which changes from "Be the first of your friends to like this" to the person who like it.

Anyhway, the font is a dark color and is hard to see against the black color of the page.

Is it possible to use CSS to change the font color to White?

Thanks,
John Nelson

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color scheme of the Like button to "dark". This changes the text from black to a light grey. Add `data-colorscheme="dark"` as an atribute inside your `<div class="fb-like">` tag.

See the [Like box plugin code generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) for more information and how to do it using the XFBML and IFRAME implementations.

To make any other changes, you're going to need to create a CSS file that restyles the iframe Facebook places inside your div AND deals with any changes FB makes to what they are serving you inside that iframe.